# Hide footer in RecyclerView when all items fit on screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made header and footer in my RecyclerView using typical solution with viewType in Adapter. It works fine, but I want to hide the footer if all RV items fit inside the screen, when nothing to scroll. Is there any way to know that all items will be displayed without scrolling and say to Adapter not to add footer in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get scroll offset of recycler view with this code

```
recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
```

Then you should check if scroll offset is more than your parent views heigh and do what you want ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find how to know when I can call computeVerticalScrollOffset after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); it has to be some callback from recycler view that all items were updated and height can be measured.

Comment: after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` you can get scroll offset @wince

Comment: I tried but it seems that it shows previous height in this case. It looks like it takes some time to get valid height. I see the follow

`adapter set data_1`
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

`adapter set data_2`
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`
`computeVerticalScrollOffset shows heigh for data_1`

`adapter set data_2`
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`
`computeVerticalScrollOffset now shows heigh for data_2`
`